# group by a field in Java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

So, I have an input JSON that looks like this:

```
[{
  "added": "2014-02-01T09:13:00Z",
  "author": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "George R R Martin",
    "added_on": "2013-02-01T09:13:00Z"
  },
  "book": {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "Game of Thrones",
    "genre": "Fantasy Fiction"
  }
},
{
  "added": "2015-02-01T09:13:00Z",
  "author": {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Patrick Rothfuss",
    "added_on": "2012-09-13T011:40:00Z"
  },
  "book": {
    "id": "15",
    "name": "The Name of the Wind",
    "genre": "Fantasy Fiction"
  }
}, {
  "added": "2016-02-01T09:13:00Z",
  "author": {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Patrick Rothfuss",
    "added_on": "2012-09-13T011:40:00Z"
  },
  "book": {
    "id": "17",
    "name": "The Wise Man's Fear",
    "genre": "Fantasy Fiction"
  }
}]
```

I need to group it basis on author.id. An author will have one object and a list of all the books he's authored. 
This is what I expect the output:

```
[
  {
    "author": "George R R Martin",
    "added_on": "2013-02-01T09:13:00Z",
    "books": [
      {
        "book_name": "Game of Thrones",
        "added": "2014-02-01T09:13:00Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "author": "Patrick Rothfuss",
    "added_on": "2012-09-13T011:40:00Z",
    "books": [
      {
        "book_name": "The Name of the Wind",
        "added": "2015-02-01T09:13:00Z"
      }, {
        "book_name": "The Wise Man's Fear",
        "added": "2016-02-01T09:13:00Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried doing it through a normal for loop -- it works. But, just for the sake of learning more about Streams, I want to try it out using Streams.

I tried this:

```
Map<Author, List<Book>> collect = authorsList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AuthorBookObj::getAuthor,
                        Collectors.mapping(AuthorBookObj::getBook, Collectors.toList())));
```

But, didn't get what I needed. Instead, it created three Maps instead of two.

Also tried this:

```
Map<AuthorTuple, List<Book>> collect = authorsList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(authors -> new AuthorTuple(authors.getAuthor().getId(),
                                authors.getAuthor().getName(), authors.getAuthor().getAddedOn()),
                        Collectors.mapping(AuthorBookObj::getBook, Collectors.toList())));
```

It also gives me three objects in the list. I expected to have two authors and corresponding books for each author.

AuthBookObj:

```
public class AuthorBookObj
{

    private String id;

    private Author author;

    private Book book;

    private String added;
    //getter, setter
}

public class Article
{
    private String name;

    private String id;

    private String genre;
}


public class Author
{
    private String name;

    private String added_on;

    private String id;
}
```

Comment: Would be better if you post code for `AuthodBookObj` and the related classes instead of the son.

Comment: You're missing equals and hashCode in Author class, aren't you?

Comment: @KorayTugay added the classes

Comment: @ILyaCyclone Yes, I don't have equals and hashCode in any of the classes

Comment: @nirvair add `equals` and `hashcode` to `Author` class and try your first solution one more time

Comment: @Ruslan what would be better approach to implement hashcode in this scenario? For Authors, later I want to sort with `added_on`, and if they are equal then I sort basis on id.

Comment: @nirvair you can sort `Author` with `Comparator`. In this case it doesn't matter how do you implement equals/hashcode. Just implement it in traditional way

Comment: @Ruslan if I make a new class (like in my second code - AuthorTuple), and add override equals and hashcode in that class, it's suppose to work, right?

Comment: @nirvair you're right, should works fine

Comment: @Ruslan Except that it isn't working :/

Comment: @nirvair share your AuthorTuple class code

Comment: my mistake. works now. thanks. And one last question, how do I format the output to the output that I mentioned in the question? Do I have to run another Stream or I can do it in the same Stream?

Comment: @nirvair Do you need output in JSON format ?

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, in JSON

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the way you handle the stream, it is in the equality of the objects.

The correct way is to use this code:

```
Map<Author, List<Book>> collect = authorsList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AuthorBookObj::getAuthor,
                        Collectors.mapping(AuthorBookObj::getBook, Collectors.toList())));
```

But now you are comparing Author objects, since the objects are different you get three entries. You need to add a hashcode and equals in the Author object that will compare the objects on the author id.

```
//code generated from intellij. 
// Author.java
 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Author author = (Author) o;
        return getId() == author.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, this works. But, I don't get the desired output as I mentioned in the question. I have created a custom object for it. How do I map it here?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have limitation on creating new POJO classes on requirement, i will do in this way

First to parse the input JSON to java object

**Response class** with `AuthorDetails` and `BookDetails` class

```
class Response {

private String addedOn;

private AuthorDetails author;

private BookDetails book;
 }
```

**AuthorDetails**

```
class AuthorDetails {
private String id;

private String name;

private String addedOn;
 }
```

**BookDetails**

```
class BookDetails {

private String id;

private String name;

private String gener;
 }
```

And i will map the input json to `List<Response>`

```
List<Response> list = Arrays.asList(new Response());
```

Then now converting `List<Response>` into desired output i have added couple of POJO classes

**AuthorAndBooks**

```
class AuthorAndBooks {

@JsonProperty("author")
private String author;

@JsonProperty("added_on")
private String addedOn;

@JsonProperty("books")
List<AuthorBooks> books;
 }
```

**AuthorBooks**

```
class AuthorBooks {

@JsonProperty("book_name")
private String name;

@JsonProperty("added")
private String added;

  }
```

Now do group by based on author name

```
Map<String, List<Response>> group = list.stream().
            collect(Collectors.groupingBy(res->res.getAuthor().getName()));
```

And now for every Author add the books

```
List<AuthorAndBooks> authorBooks = group.entrySet().stream().
            map(entry->{
                AuthorAndBooks ab = new AuthorAndBooks();
                ab.setAuthor(entry.getKey());
                ab.setAddedOn(entry.getValue().stream().findFirst().get().getAddedOn());

                ab.setBooks(entry.getValue().stream().map(authorBook->{
                    AuthorBooks books = new AuthorBooks();
                    books.setName(authorBook.getBook().getName());
                    books.setAdded(authorBook.getAddedOn());
                    return books;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return ab;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You must override `equals` and `hashCode`. If you fail to do so, your class will violate the general contract for `hashCode`, which will prevent it from functioning properly in collections such as `HashMap` and `HashSet`. The Author class’s failure to override `hashCode` causes the two equal instances to have unequal hash codes, in violation of the `hashCode` contract. Add this to your `Author` class.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof Author && ((Author) obj).getId().equals(id);
}
```

With that in place, the following code snippet should work as expected.

```
Map<Author, List<Article>> booksByAuthor = authorsList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors
        .groupingBy(AuthorBookObj::getAuthor, 
            Collectors.mapping(AuthorBookObj::getBook, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all want to pay attention to `"added"` field from input JSON. What does this belong to? I guess it belongs to `Book` object. If so it would be good to place this field (if it possible) inside `Book` object. Then you need to deserialize this json to java objects. It can be done by `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` But you can use any json framework for this.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
AuthorBookObj[] objs = mapper.readValue(inputJson, AuthorBookObj[].class);
```

Then you need to group these objects and your first solution is well suited:

```
Map<Author, List<Book>> collect = Arrays.stream(objs)
    .collect(groupingBy(AuthorBookObj::getAuthor,
            mapping(AuthorBookObj::getBook, toList())));
```

How it was mentioned in previous answer you need to make sure there are `equals/hashcode` methods in your class that is used for as key in `Map` (In this case `Author`). The main confuse now is that desirable json output doesn't represent `Map`. It is just list of some custom object with fields like `author`, `added_on`, `books` which is list also.

So to achieve this goal you need to transform your `Map<Author, List<Book>>` to list of custom objects. For example:

```
public class PublicationInfo {

    private String author;
    private String added_on;
    private List<BookBriefInfo> books;
    ...
}

public class BookBriefInfo {
    private String book_name;
    private String added;
    ...
}


List<PublicationInfo> infos = new ArrayList<>();

for (Map.Entry<Author, List<Book>> entry : collect.entrySet()) {
    PublicationInfo info = new PublicationInfo();
    info.setAuthor(entry.getKey().getName());
    info.setAdded_on(entry.getKey().getAdded_on());
    List<BookBriefInfo> bookInfos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Book book : entry.getValue()) {
        bookInfos.add(new BookBriefInfo(book.getBook_name(), book.getAdded()))
    }
    info.setBooks(bookInfos);
}
```

Finally it can be serialized:

```
String jsonResult = mapper.writeValueAsString(infos);
```

By the way, to get json output formatted just configure it:

```
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
```